# Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Symbol with CairoMakie and Julia

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I want to create pie charts with julia and [cairomakie](https://docs.makie.org/stable/examples/plotting_functions/pie/) with a equal aspect ratio of axis.

When I execute the following code:

```
using CairoMakie
fig, ax, plt =Makie.pie([5,7,1,4],
                 color = [:yellow, :orange, :red, :blue],
                 radius = 4,
                 inner_radius = 2,
                 strokecolor = :black,
                 strokewidth = 2,
                )
save("myfigure.png", fig)
```

I get:

[image]

and when I add this line to force the aspect ratio (as show in https://docs.makie.org/stable/examples/plotting_functions/pie/):

```
fig, ax, plt =Makie.pie([5,7,1,4],
                 color = [:yellow, :orange, :red, :blue],
                 radius = 4,
                 inner_radius = 2,
                 strokecolor = :black,
                 strokewidth = 2,
                 axis = (autolimitaspect = 1) # line added
                )
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Symbol
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T at essentials.jl:171
  Symbol(::Any...) at strings/basic.jl:227
```

**Do you have an idea of what's going wrong with my command ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

```
axis = (autolimitaspect = 1, )
```

Note the trailing comma after the number `1`. This comma is necessary to create a named tuple, when the tuple has only *a single element*, otherwise, it is just equal to writing

```
axis = autolimitaspect = 1
```

which again is equivalent to writing

```
autolimitaspect = 1
axis = autolimitaspect
```

And now you see why `autolimitaspect` is suddenly an `Int`.

The trailing comma is also necessary when creating single-element tuples:

```
julia> (3) |> typeof
Int64

julia> (3,) |> typeof
Tuple{Int64}
```